# google signin button press detection ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, google-signin

I am struggling with the google documentation on their login buttons. Basically, I want to add a activity indicator to the screen as soon as I press the google sign in button. However, there are only two functions that really gets called from the documentation below

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/protocol_g_i_d_sign_in_u_i_delegate-p#a3674af917a79f4b87a58f3f8ff4d4002

1. `- signInWillDispatch:error:`

   The sign-in flow has finished selecting how to proceed, and the UI should no longer display a spinner or other "please wait" element. More...
2. `- signIn:didSignInForUser:withError:`

   The sign-in flow has finished and was successful if error is nil. More...`

I dont know where I can put my beginActivityIndicator code as I dont know what function gets called immediately after I press the Google login button.

Thanks,

--UPDATE WITH CODE --
Below are four functions that I have in my loginVC that inherits from GIDSignInUIDelegate and GIDSignInDelegate. Pretty much I need to get to the functions before SignInWillDispatch so that I can initiate the activity indicator. However, I could not find where it is in the documentation. I tried including tap gesture recogniser on the google button. When I do that though, the login function stops from working completely as if it is just a blank UIView

```
    // Google login buttob
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self


    // Uncomment to automatically sign in the user.
    //GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()

    // TODO(developer) Configure the sign-in button look/feel
    let googleSignInBtn = GIDSignInButton()
    googleSignInBtn.frame.size = loginButton.frame.size
    googleSignInBtn.center.x = loginButton.center.x
    googleSignInBtn.center.y = loginButton.center.y + 80
    googleSignInBtn.style = .Wide
    self.view.addSubview(googleSignInBtn)



func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, presentViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
    print("Signed in with google")
}

func signInWillDispatch(signIn: GIDSignIn!, error: NSError!) {
    print("Signin Will Dispatch")
}

func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, dismissViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
    print("GoogleSignInDismiss")
}

func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {

    activityIndicatorBegin() // Having the activity indicator start here is too late. I need it to start as soon as the google button is pressed. Otherwise there would be a moment just after the google view dismisses without activity indicator

    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    let authentication = user.authentication
    let credential = FIRGoogleAuthProvider.credentialWithIDToken(authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

    FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
        if let error = error {
            self.showErrorAlert("Error Sign in Firebase with google", message: error.localizedDescription)
        } else {

        }
        self.activityIndicatorEnd()  
    }
}

func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWithUser user:GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {
    // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
    print("didDisconnectWithUser")
}
```

Comment: post your code  ...

Comment: Don't know IOS that much, but be sure to check that "guide" : https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating and this one : https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in

Comment: code posted Captain. I did go through the developers guid and here is where I am stuck. Cheers

Comment: When exactly do you want to start the indicator? Mark it in the code where it is that you want the activity indicator to start.

Comment: The googleSignInBtn code is inside viewDidLoad. The button is created programatically. I can not add the activity indicator in the viewDidload as it would not make sense. I wish I can mark where I want to start but I cant mark it because I dont know where that piece of code is. Here is the flow. Program Loaded->Google button initiated in viewDidLoad-> User taps on the button-> activity indicator begin (this is where I couldnt find the function to put the code in) -> user enter email and pwd to login-> activity indicator end (This part I know where to put) -> perform segue

Comment: you can fix an activity indicator in the view andin  viewDidLoad you can hide it. when button press you can show and animate.

Comment: That's the question, I do not see a function that triggers on button press. In a simple case where I have a IBAction of a UIButton, I know I can put the code there. However, this google login button is a UIControl which inherits from a UIView. And the google login screen seems to magically appear when the "Sign in with google" thing is pressed. Earliest event I can catch signInWillDispatch which displays seconds AFTER the username/Password google screen dismisses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I could not solve it by creating the button programatically like above. What I did was created a UIButton and simply do the following

```
@IBAction func signInWithGoogleBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    activityIndicatorBegin()
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}
```